# Need help On Quote Line Item

Tags: quote, quotelineitem, quote-template

[image: Quote Line Item]

**Requirement 1**:-I need to add custom field **Product_Services__c** picklist

**Requirement 2**:-I need to show picklist values based on Product.If product A then Picklist Values P1,P2,P3.IF product B then P3,P4,P5.

Please suggest How can i achieve these 2 requirements.

Comment: -1 from me because this sounds like a 'do my work for me' request. I don't see any attempt at research here.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr version:**

I don't think what you're asking for is feasible, and you (or your manager) need to rethink your requirements (as well as doing some independent research).

**long version:**

This is a lot more work than I think you think it is.

The page that you're working with is `quoteitm/multilineitem.jsp`. It's a standard UI that Salesforce provides, but doesn't allow you to tinker around with too much.

There is [this help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=layouts_opp_product_multiline.htm&type=0) which outlines how to add a field to the multilineitem.jsp page for Opportunity Line Items. The process is identical for adding fields to the same page for Quote Line Items.

> 1. From the object management settings for opportunity products, go to Page Layouts.
> 2. Next to the name of an opportunity product page layout, click Edit.
> 3. Click Edit Multi-Line Layout.
> 4. Move fields between Available Fields and Selected Fields.
>
>    - To customize which fields display in the layout, select one or more fields in Available Fields and click Add or Remove.
>    - To sort fields in the layout, select one or more fields in Selected Fields and click Up or Down.
>    - To select multiple fields individually, use CTRL+click.
>    - To select multiple fields as a group, use SHIFT+click.
> 5. Click Save to apply your changes.

That can get your picklist onto the page, but I believe that making your picklist dependent on product name is out of reach. If you have a controlling field for a picklist, it must either be a checkbox field, or another picklist field.

For that, you'd need to make a custom controller or controller extension and manually create & maintain the dependency logic (which is well beyond the scope of your question). This also means that you'd need to override multilineitem.jsp, which is another nightmare altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Requirement 1: simply create a picklist field.

Requirement 2: Do these picklist values need to vary based on product, or based on *type* of product? 
If its the latter, you could simply create a handful of **record types** on the Product object, and then define separate picklist values for each record type.